# Derivative of an Inverse Function

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

Can someone please give me a simple proof of this-

If $f$ is differentiable on an interval containing $c$ and $f'(c) \neq 0$, then $f^{-1}$ (inverse of $f$) is differentiable at $f(c)$.

I can see that from examples, but I need a general proof. I'd really appreciate it.

Also do i need to study extensive Maths Proof for a Physics Undergrad Degree?

Comment: Actually, I find relatively strange not to prove that $f^{-1}$ exists at $f(c)$. And I find even more strange not to suppose that $f$ is *continuously differentiable* on a neighborhood of $c$. Because it seems to me that $\displaystyle{f(x)=x^2\chi_{\Bbb Q}(x)+x}$ is differentiable at $x=0$, and the derivative here is not zero. Or you just assume $f^{-1}$ exists?

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem 5** (Calculus by Spivak 4th edition, page 237-238)
*Proof.*
Let $b = f(a)$. Then
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f^{-1}(b + h) - f^{-1}(b)}{h} = \displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0} 
\dfrac{f^{-1}(b + h) - a}{h}$$
Now any number $b + h$ in the domain of $f^{-1}$ can be written in the form
$$f(a + k) = b + h$$
for a unique $k$. Then
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f^{-1}(b + h) - a}{h} 
= \lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f^{-1}(f(a + k)) - a}{f(a + k) - b} 
= \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{k}{f(a + k) - f(a)}$$
We have
$$f^{-1}(b + h) = a + k \Longleftrightarrow k = f^{-1}(b + h) - f^{-1}(b)$$
Since $f$ is a one-one and continuous function, $f^{-1}$ is also continuous at $b$. This means that $k$ approaches $0$ as $h$ approaches $0$. Since
$$\lim_{k\to 0} \dfrac{f(a + k) - f(a)}{k} = f'(a) = f'(f^{-1}(b)) \neq 0$$
which implies
$$(f^{-1})'(b) = \dfrac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(b))}$$

Comment: See my comment above, isn't there another hypothesis for this theorem?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Of course, this proof requires $f^{-1}$ to exist.

Comment: Ah, ok. I felt uncomfortable with "prove that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable" in the question, without even stating its existence, as it's not guaranteed by other hypotheses on $f$. Thanks to have clarified this. +1